# How can I add a vertical scroll to the list in Brightscript?

Tags: video-player, roku, brightscript

I am trying to customize the video player example that comes with the SDK. I am displaying the videoplayer on the left side of the screen and the playlist on the right side with the navigation through this playlist.

However I am able to display only few videos on the rightside. Hence I need to add s**croll to the playlist so that I can display all the videos there**.

I have reserched on it and found the **rotextscreen** that provides scroll but that opens a whole new screen which doesnot serve my purpose as I want to show the playlsit on tthe right side of the player more like **you tube**.

I cannot use **Rogridscreen** for the same reason as **rotextscreen**.

Is there any other component i can use to display the playlist and add the vertical scroll to the playlist or any other approach I can take??

I am a bit lost at the moment. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [roListScreen](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roListScreen), a scrollable list will be on the left

Comment: Thanks a ton for reply. However my requirement is to show the list on the right side of the screen and a video player on the left side which doesnot seem possible using this. roList will take up a whole new screena as I cannot find amy method like SetDestRect similar to rovideoplayer's method. Can you suggest me  any workaround to meet my requirement??

Comment: If `roVideoPlayer` can at all work with `roListScreen`, change your requirements. I kid you not, that would be the way to go **if** the two controls are compatible. If not however, you are left to build your own scrollable list with `roImageCanvas`